# Path with 0 opacity and visible stroke in AI or PS

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, transparency, appearance

Is it possible to draw a line using the pen tool and set it to have a visible stroke, 0% opacity and 30% fill. I need it to create a route map, so lots of drawing with pen tool.

See examples:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Cai's solution is the smart one - the roadline is easier to edit. Please, correct it to be the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Appearance panel (*Window → Appearance*) to do this without expanding your stroke (so your path is still editable, you can change the stroke width etc.).

- Add two strokes, the bottom one will be the outer stroke and the top one will act as the "fill", so set the bottom a few points wider.
- Set your top stroke to 30% (or whatever you want) opacity.
- From the transparency panel of the object (click the very bottom "Opacity", not one attached to a stroke or fill), check "Knockout Group" (this will make any transparency set on the object knockout everything below it).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

- draw a curve with the wanted total width,but no fill
- convert the curve itself to a filled area; Goto Object > Path > Outline Stroke, then Ungroup => you have separate outline and fill curve. See them both by removing all fill colors and by setting a narrow black stroke to both
- choose good widths and stroke colors to the curves, no fill needed
- change the opacity of the fill curve in the appearance panel

[image]

Comment: You can do this without expanding the stroke